# PHP Retrieve the headers of a response to a POST request a key-value pair

Tags: php, post

I have this php scripts:

```
$url = "https://mysite/web/session/authenticate";
$data = array (
 'params' => 
 array (
   'db' => 'mydb',
   'login' => 'myuserid',
   'password' => 'myuserpwd',
 ),
);

$data = json_encode($data);
$options = array(
 'http' => array(
   'header'  =>    "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" 
                 . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
   'method'  => 'POST',
   'content' => $data,
 )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

From the server response I need to retrieve a key-value pair (set-cookie) contained in the headers.
[Response fron POSTMAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Py0E.jpg)
How can I do?
Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend using [Guzzle](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies), it will manage cookies for you.

Comment: Or PHP-cURL, which also has options for cookie handling.

Comment: But if you want to write it yourself, more low-level - https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php exists.

Comment: Or use the `$_COOKIE` super variable, it should contains the values you're looking for.